# Adf Copy task with Excel in a foreach loop

Tags: excel, azure, azure-data-factory

within Azure Adf, I have an excel file with 4 tabs named Sheet1-Sheet4

I would like to loop through the excel creating a CSV per tab

I have created a SheetsNames parameter in the pipeline with a default value of ["Sheet1","Sheet2","Sheet3","Sheet4"]

How do I use this with the copy task to loop with the tabs?

Comment: please visit https://www.reddit.com/r/AZURE/comments/nd0crr/adf_copy_an_excel_sheet_with_multiple_sheets_into/ and check if it is useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

1. Create a SheetsNames parameter in the pipeline with a default value of ["Sheet1","Sheet2","Sheet3","Sheet4"].
2. Add a For Each activity and type `@pipeline().parameters. SheetsNames` in the Items option.
3. Within the For Each activity, add a copy activity.
4. Create Source dataset and create a parameter named sheetName with empty default value.

[image]

5. Navigate to the Connection setting of the Source dataset and check Edit in the Sheet name option. Then type `@dataset().sheetName` in it.

[image]

6. Navigate to the Source setting of the Copy data activity and pass `@item()` to the sheetName.

[image]

7. Create a Sink dataset and it's setting is similar to the Source dataset.

[image]

[image]

[image]

8. Run the pipeline and get this result:

[image]

Comment: Perfect! I was trying to do something similar but veered off the beaten path